# How to compare Python3 range with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python2, when you call `range`, you get a list. In Python3, when you call `range`, you get a range and avoid instantiating all the elements at once.

I want to compare a range `x` with a list `y`, to check whether the two element sequences are the same. I can do `list(x) == y` but that defeats the efficiency that Python3 range supposedly gives me by not instantiating all the elements, so I have more verbose code with no benefit compared to Python2. I could use `all(map(lambda p: p[0] == p[1], zip(x, y)))`, which uses constant (additional) space but that feels like writing a legal document just to buy a cup of coffee.

Is there a way that takes constant space but uses less verbose and more readable code than the `all(...)`? More generally I often find myself converting Python3 non-list things like range and map to lists so that I can use simple, readable, code to process them, and that seems to defeat the purpose of the Python3 range, map, etc.

Comment: It took you probably 10x more time to write this question than it will take someone to read the solution you already have, but for some reason feel unhappy with. Maybe a bit of pragmatism would help? Just my personal opinion: go with the solution you have, it meets the memory optimization and has nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Python3 is supposed to be an upgrade but I find myself calling `list()` on range, map, zip, etc all the time, resulting in more verbose code compared to Python2, so  I want to know if I'm missing something. Maybe there's a technique that will make the Python3 code better than the Python2 one.

Comment: Most of the time you need to use `map`, `zip`, or `range`, you shouldn't need to convert them into `list`s. If you give some more details or ask different questions, we might be able to help you figure out what you could do differently. In this case, why are you comparing a list to a range?

Comment: @jirassimok In this particular use-case, I have as input an unsorted list of integers `x`. I want to check that after sorting, they are some contiguous range. E.g. `list(range(2, 6)) == sorted(x)` under Python3 and `range(2, 6) == sorted(x)` under Python2. When `x == [2, 5, 4, 3]`, the result is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` and compare the two elementwise.

```
def compare_sequences(seq1, seq2):
    if len(seq1) != len(seq2):
        return False

    for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2):
        if a != b:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

But you shouldn't actually do this. The performance gains are minimal, and your code will be less readable.

Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-pythons-xrange-and-range/) is good description of the `Python 3's range` function, which is essentially `Python 2's xrange`, and its advantage.  Besides `list` you could cast the *new* `range` function to other types, such as `set` for comparison.  For example:

```
x = range(4)
L1 = [0,1,2,3]
S1 = {0,1,2,3}

print(L1 == list(x))  ## True
print(S1 == set(x))  ## True
```

As a side note, `all(map(lambda p: p[0] == p[1], zip(x, y)))` will be incorrect comparison `if x = [1,2,3] and y=[1,2,3,4]`.